# How can I work out the meaning of the return codes for BPF helper functions?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, bpf, ebpf

I am writing a `BPF_PROG_TYPE_SOCKET_OPS` program and I am seeing the following in `/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_pipe`:

```
<...>-12586 [001] ....  6972.409111: 0: update err: -95
```

when I load it due to the following snippet:

```
ret = bpf_sock_map_update(ops, &sock_ops, &idx, BPF_ANY);
if (ret < 0) {
    bpf_debug("update err: %d\n", ret);
}
```

How can I work out what -95 means? When I look in https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/alpha/include/uapi/asm/errno.h I see:

```
#define ENOCSI      95  /* No CSI structure available */
```

Is this the correct way to find the meaning of the error? And what is the meaning of the description if so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was [EOPNOTSUPP](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/asm-generic/errno.h#L78) from [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/net/core/sock_map.c#L435). This was caused by the socket not being 'full' when trying to add the socket (i.e. the TCP connection [must be established](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/net/core/sock_map.c#L383)).